# Attach screen video on allure-playwright-reporter

Tags: javascript, node.js, allure, playwright

Is there a way to have screen recording of each test in allure-playwright-reporter. I am able to capture screenshots for each test but also wish to have screen recordings on dashboard. What can be done to achieve this?

This is my playwright.config.js, just for reference

```
/** @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig} */
const config = {
    use : {
        launchOptions: {
            devtools: false
        },
        contextOptions:{
            recordVideo: {
                dir: "../test-results/videos/"
            }
        },
        testDir: './tests',
        headless: false,
        viewport: { width: 1280, height: 900 },
        channel: "chrome",
        screenshot: "on",
        video: "on",
        trace: "on"
    },
    testMatch: /traderTest.js/,
    retries: 0,
    reporter: [["list"], ["json", { outputFile: "test-results.json"}] ,['experimental-allure-playwright']]
};
module.exports = config;
```

This is how the dashboard looks like
[image]

As you can see under test body, I have trace and screenshot but I also need screen recording.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this here https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues. I think,  they usually respond on that platform.

Comment: Okay, I just asked. Waiting for their response.